# golang selective conversion of string to lower case

Tags: regex, string, go, iteration, tolower

I am working with an ldap object where I am retrieving some entries from Activedirectory. The results are in such a way that the realm is returned in uppercase, like `CN=bob,DC=example,DC=com` instead of `cn=bob,dc=example,dc=com`. Is there a way to selectively convert the `CN` and `DC` substrings to lowercase? Sofar, I was using `strings.split` multiple times (using "," first and then iterating again using "=") to get to the point where I can get CN, DC, etc. into a list, and then using strings.ToLower on them. Is there a better and smarter way to get this done, possibly using regex so that I can possibly avoid two iterations?

Comment: what about this regex: [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN1oF4/1)

Comment: Thank you @lbarros, I could get that match with `([A-Z]{2})=.+,([A-Z]{2})=.+,([A-Z]{2})=.+` but the number of fields could be varying, if an `OU` comes in between. It varies based on the returned entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a regex way to make all uppercase chunks of text followed with a `=` tp lower case:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
        "regexp"
)

func main() {
        input := "CN=bob,DC=example,DC=com"
        r := regexp.MustCompile(`[A-Z]+=`)
        fmt.Println(r.ReplaceAllStringFunc(input, func(m string) string {
                return strings.ToLower(m)
        }))
}
```

See the [Playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/62656ElRgh)

The regex - `[A-Z]+=` - matches 1 or more uppercase ASCII letters and a `=` after them. Then, inside the [`ReplaceAllStringFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc), we can use an "anonymous function" to return a modified match value.

Comment: Nice and clean. The regex part is converted whereas the other parts, whether upper or lower, remains same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

```
strings.Replace(results, "CN", "cn", -1)
```

can help? https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace

Comment: The realm part could be anything, and any number, based on the return value.